# Killed my old MacBook Pro. Any recommendations to help extend the life of my M1 Macook Air internal SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, video, apple-silicon, recording

I recently killed my old (2012) MacBook Pro's hard drive by doing something I didn't realize was a problem. I've now purchased a nice little M1 MacBook Air to replace the old workhorse MBP, and it's only got a tiny 256GB SSD in it. I've already done the same workflow described below a few times in the last few weeks and, being paranoid, am wondering how to ensure this laptop lasts more than 2 years. I've been reading that SSDs wear out faster with frequent writes/rewrites.

Here's my workflow:

I attend a *lot* of training webinars and Zoom video calls with clients: 5 to 10 webinars and 5 to 10 calls every week, most being in the 1 to 2 hour range. I record them using Camtasia (it just happens to be the software I've got installed) and export to MP4, but it creates huge files, so I then use Handbrake to compress them down to either 570p or 480p depending on the content, saved in a different directory, same name as the original Camtasia MP4 output. Once I have the final output, I back that up on to an external hard drive (a few years old Western Digital HDD) - it's an 8TB drive, with just under 7TB of space remaining: I only use that to read back from, it's not used as a read/write device.

Apparently, doing this over and over again (a *lot* of online webinars/calls, remember) for 2+ years was sufficient to kill the old MacBook's internal hard drive, the original HDD. The steps: write and erase the Camtasia .trec file, write and erase the original Camtasia 1080p file, write the Handbrake file in one directory, overwrite the original Camtasia 1080p file. Every time the MBP's internal drive got close to full, I'd move stuff to the external backup and erase the files on the internal drive.

What would be your recommended solution? Should I not write anything on that internal SSD, other than plain old text/PDF documents? Should I use an external drive from the very first step of recording the training videos? Record the video on the internal drive and then export the MP4 to an external drive? SSD or HDD external drive?

Am I overthinking this? Because it's just a 256GB SSD (yeah, dumb choice, but I was watching pennies that day), I've already recorded 100GB plus a couple of times over 3-4 days (Camtasia 2021 outputs ginormous files), and I've already erased my .trec files a few times.

Any help/insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember SSD ≠ Hard Drive and they fail in very different ways. I would not worry. On my system over the past 9 days I've read 13.2 TB and written 11.9 TB – much larger than your estimated ~200GB over a similar time frame. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Also consider that your computer was likely 5-10 years old, which is not an unusual lifespan for spinning disk failure

Comment: Replace the harddrive in the old mac with an ssd and restore from time machine.  New life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Am I overthinking this?**

Yes.

Mechanical 'spinning rust' hard drives have a typical lifespan of less than 5 years. Excessive work could shorten that.
*(You could replace the hard drive in your 2012 MBP with an SSD (get a SATA 2.5" type), and you would notice a considerable improvement in the speed of the Mac.)*

The myth of needing to guard precious writes on SSDs stems largely from old technology when SSDs first became 'mainstream' c. 10 years ago. Most SSDs now have lifespans that exceed the useful life of the device they are inside.

Estimates for the lifespan of Apple's M1 SSDs (256 GB) are at least 300 TB of writes (though could be [significantly higher](https://www.howtogeek.com/322856/how-long-do-solid-state-drives-really-last/)), so if my maths is correct, you've got over 8 years of 100GB per day.

One caveat is that it's not clear whether M1 Macs can function if the on-chip storage fails.

Also, re your 'backup drive': remember that a backup is a second copy. You should always be prepared for any storage device to suddenly stop working, by having another device with the same files on it.

Comment: Re your caveat: The M1 Mac can't boot any disk without the working SSD on the motherboard. This is because booting requires code and data from the SSD - think of it as firmware equivalent being on the SSD.

Comment: @Gilby Might it depend on the nature of the failure? I guess we won't know for sure until we have failed examples in the wild. But 'preparing for failure' is always good.

Comment: I think it is is well known. Read Howard Oakley's blog - like this one https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/14/m1-macs-radically-change-boot-and-recovery/

Comment: I can't see anything there that proves that failure of the user portion also means failure of the 1TR segment. The smart design would be to have them separate somehow on the chip, so that the 'main' SSD could fail but not bring down the 1TR.